# Customizing Chapter Names in Exam Class

Tags: titlesec, exam

I am preparing a multiple choice test book for my students in exam class. This book covers a few different topic, so I want to add chapter names at the beginning of each topic. As you can see in my MWE, it complies without any error, but `\titlesec` do not modify the chapter name, it just writes the chapter name. Could you kindly address the problem here ?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\footer{}{\thepage}{}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\newcommand\ctformatchapter[1]{%                                                                                                                                                                      
    \parbox[b][6cm][b]{\dimexpr.5\textwidth\relax}{%                                                                                                                                                  
        \raggedright%                                                                                                                                                                                 
        \textcolor{cyan!50!blue}{\textsf{#1}}%                                                                                                                                                        
    }%                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%                                                                                                                                                                      
{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\bfseries\selectfont}%                                                                                                                                                          
{%                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    \raggedleft{%                                                                                                                                                                                     
        \begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{Untitled.png}
            \put (38,22) {{\fontsize{50pt}{50pt}\selectfont\textsf{\Roman{chapter}}}}
            \put (20,50) {\textcolor{cyan!50!blue}{\textsf{Chapter}}}
        \end{overpic}
    }%                                                                                                                                                                                                
}%                                                                                                                                                                                                    
{-6.5cm}%                                                                                                                                                                                             
{\ctformatchapter}%                                                                                                                                                                                   
[\phantomsection]

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

It produces:[image]

Thanks in advance,

Cheers.

Comment: Exam class uses `\LoadClass{article}`, but your MWE deosn't work with article class either.  Come to think of it, article doesn't support \chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Article class, and therefore exam, doesn't support `\chapter`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\footer{}{\thepage}{}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\newcommand\ctformatsection[1]{%                                                                                                                                                                      
    \parbox[b][6cm][b]{\dimexpr.5\textwidth\relax}{%                                                                                                                                                  
        \raggedright%                                                                                                                                                                                 
        \textcolor{cyan!50!blue}{\textsf{#1}}%                                                                                                                                                        
    }%                                                                                                                                                                                                
}
\titleformat{\section}[display]%                                                                                                                                                                      
{\fontsize{20pt}{20pt}\bfseries\selectfont}%                                                                                                                                                          
{%                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    \raggedleft{%                                                                                                                                                                                     
        \begin{overpic}[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
            \put (38,22) {{\fontsize{50pt}{50pt}\selectfont\textsf{\Roman{section}}}}
            \put (20,50) {\textcolor{cyan!50!blue}{\textsf{Chapter}}}
        \end{overpic}
    }%                                                                                                                                                                                                
}%                                                                                                                                                                                                    
{-6.5cm}%                                                                                                                                                                                             
{\ctformatsection}%                                                                                                                                                                                   
[\phantomsection]

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Including the files of `\titlesec` (downloaded from CTAN website) in the working directory, this block of code actually works, and produces the MWE. Thanks anyway.